# Can I place a asp:datalist inside a repeater control and databind it?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, datalist

Can I place a asp:datalist inside a repeater control and databind it for each time its repeated? Using VB.NET btw..

Cheers! --Jonesy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:
1. Nest the DataList in the Repeater
2. Bind each repeated Datalist during the Repeater's ItemDataBound event 
3. Turn off their ViewStates,if they are not required.

**Update:**

i.e.

Script Side:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
            </asp:DataList>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

In Code:

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound
        Dim DataList1 As DataList = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("DataList1"), DataList)
...Databind here ....

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. How do i do step 2? 

this is what i have done to databind the repeater:

 Repeater1.DataSource = dtAssets
 Repeater1.DataBind()

How can I access a control inside that repeater? I've tried this:

Dim DataList1 As DataList = DirectCast(Repeater1.FindControl("DataList1"), DataList)

But i get an error saying:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

please help! -- Jonesy

Comment: sorry new to repeaters, what is the ItemDataBound?

Comment: Hi i figured it out. You were right about needing it in the ItemDataBind. Thanks!

Comment: oh one more question if you'll help me. Can I pass a variable to the repeaters ItemDataBound sub? It would be a variable bound to the repeater.

Comment: You can show any databound element to UI using #Eval and can access on server side using e.item.DataItem

Comment: I ended up using a hidden label to use variables. I know its probably not the way its supposed to be but it works well. On repeater databind i set the text of the label to the id of the asset (in this case) then when i call the itemdatabind sub to get the asset history I use the labels text value. --jonesy