# Create multiple table dynamically and each of the table add multiple rows and columns dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is not a problem to create single table and add rows and columns dynamically but the problem is while I'm trying to create multiple tables with all rows and columns dynamically then I'm facing problem.

I'm retrieving a datatable with 4 rows and 5 columns. For every row, I want to put it in a table with its column values.
Is there any solution?

Comment: Can u please explain a little bit more or any code which ur working on? Which language ur are using? what is problem statement (to suggest alternative if any)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Repeater` control in your asp.net page

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx

Define in the `<itemtemplate>` the structure of your desired table.

Add as a `DataSource` of your `Repeater` a method in your code `DataSource="<%# MethodName() %>"`

In that method, for each row add a new item in the `Repeater` and populate it with your row information. It's like creating single tables dynamically, only with a different logic.

It's quite a fuss (don't know why would you want a different table for each row), but `Repeater` controls are ussualy the way to solve situations when multiple controls are needed.

Comment: Thanks Coral for your suggestion. I'll try the use of Repeater control. But I got the solution by using DataList control.

Comment: See this question with reference to using `DataList` controls in `Repeater` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552032/can-i-place-a-aspdatalist-inside-a-repeater-control-and-databind-it  (it reffers to vb, not c#, but the approach is similar).